# Default value for DatabaseGenerated

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I can define a identity primary key with:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set;}
}
```

But if I don't add data annotations what's the type generated by default? Like this:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
}
```

Identity or depending on the database when I create the database?

I don't find the subject in the official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties

Comment: What happened when you tried it for yourself?

Comment: @jmcilhinney I only have SQL Server, and in SQL Server the default is Identity.

Comment: So you're specifically asking, without specifically asking, what happens on databases other than SQL Server?

Comment: @jmcilhinney mmh... yes

Comment: **Conventions** section from the documentation link: *"By convention, primary keys that are of an integer or GUID data type will be setup to have values generated on add. All other properties will be setup with no value generation."*

Comment: @IvanStoev Identity then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By convention, EF looks for property named YourEntityName + Id or just Id, and knows it's for to specify the PK. So implicitly `[Key]` and `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` attributes performed on this property.